# Bind UserControls property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, opacity

Im kind of weird atm.

First thing i want to do is binding the opacity of my usercontrol to an boolean property with converter. Im on a fullscreen WPF app with a little menu. If the menu is open anything else should get a lower opacity. Kinda grey everything out.

Second thing is the menu shouldnt inherit the opacity from the usercontrol.

Dont know what i could google. My efforts to find something usefully was futile.
Hope you can help me.

Greets Lucas

View:

```
<UserControl ....>
...

    <view:InvisibleButtonView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                            Height="75" Width="75"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

    <view:IdleScreenView Visibility="{Binding IsWelcomeScreenActive,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=NegativeBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <view:WelcomeScreenView Visibility="{Binding IsWelcomeScreenActive,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <view:DateView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <view:InvisibleInputView Height="25" Width="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Cursor=""/>

    <view:MainMenuView Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="{Binding IsAnyMenuActive, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                         Height="300" Width="250" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: so, your user controls are the MenuItems? do you have any code we can look at or should we just guess your layout?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 updated it again..If IsAnyMenuActive triggers PropertyChanged opacity should change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helped me with a background view

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuActiveBackgroundColor" Color="Green"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuInactiveBackgroundColor" Color="Tomato"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnyMenuIsActive}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuActiveBackgroundColor}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnyMenuIsActive}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuInactiveBackgroundColor}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```